# Sidebar not showing up on homepage

Tags: sidebar

I am using the [Nameless Child Theme](http://monicaguerraleiria.com/2012/11/26/nameless-free-genesis-child-theme/) for Wordpress. My sidebar is showing up on all other pages except for the home (blog posts) page which is the most important page for it to show up on.

My site is http://mayziesdogblog.com.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: I see a sidebar...?

Comment: I see the sidebar...? You might need to clear your browser cache if you're editing code and don't see the sidebar.

Comment: What are you viewing the site on? When the viewport gets too narrow, the sidebar drops below the content. I believe this is by design.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [`body_class`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class) set for the home page called `full-width-content`. That suggests to me that:

1. The homepage intentionally does not have a sidebar. You will need to edit the template appropriate template file to change that. That should be `index.php`, `home.php`, or `front-page.php`.
2. or there is a dynamic sidebar for that page but you haven't placed any widgets in it so nothing shows up. Look in Appearance->Widgets and see if there is a sidebar that seems like it should be the front page sidebar.

Either way this does look to be by design. I could do better if you could find the template for that page and post the code.

Answer (score 0):

Just add following style and you'll be fine :)

```
#content {
    width: 68%;
}
```

Maybe you could wrap it in media query but I think it's not needed:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {

  #content {
      width: 68%;
  }

}
```

Comment: I just noticed that this question is asked 4 years ago :)